# Lucene Hibernate-Search - Filtering Query-String

Tags: java, filter, lucene, wildcard, hibernate-search

Is there a way to filter a query string which contains wildcard-stars?

**The goal:** I want to find the text phrase "*The capital of germany is Berlin*" out of many others, when my query string is *capi* of* germa**.

**Environment:** There is an analyzer-definition done with `@AnalyzerDef` which contains a StopWordFilter. I use this analyzer for index-building and searching via Lucene-Query-parser.

So while indexing something like "capital germany Berlin" is indexed - stopwords are removed.

**The problem:** The Query-string isnt handled the same way, I guess because of the wildcard-stars.

The resulting lucene-query is: *+(field:capi*) +(field:of*) +(field:germa*)*
If I remove the wildcard-stars the lucene-query is: *+(field:capi) +(field:germa)* The of is removed.

**The Question:** Is there a way to get rid of the stopword of even the query string contains wildcard-stars? Is there another way to do the trick - like setting an option "wildcardeverthing"?

**Note:** I want to reuse the predefined analyzer, so i dont have to reimplement the filter-chain to handle the query-strings.

**Some Code:**

Analyzer-Definition (actual version is german):

```
@AnalyzerDef(
    name = "whitespaceAnalyzer_DE",
    tokenizer = @TokenizerDef( factory = WhitespaceTokenizerFactory.class ),
    filters = {
        @TokenFilterDef( factory = StandardFilterFactory.class ),
        @TokenFilterDef( factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class ),
        @TokenFilterDef(
            factory = GermanStopFilterFactory.class,
            params = { @Parameter(name = "ignoreCase",value = "true")}),
        @TokenFilterDef(
            factory = SnowballPorterFilterFactory.class,
            params = { @Parameter(  name = "language",  value = "German2")})
        })
```

The `GermanStopFilterFactory` is like its named a filter for german stopwords.

Searching:

```
...
String queryString = "capi* of* germa*";

FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession( getCurrentSession() );

Analyzer whitespaceAnalyzer_DE = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().getAnalyzer("whitespaceAnalyzer_DE" );

Map<String, Analyzer> fieldAnalyzer = new HashMap<String, Analyzer>( 3 );
fieldAnalyzer.put( "field", standardAnalyzer_DE );

PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper perFieldAnalyzer = new PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper( new StandardAnalyzer(), fieldAnalyzer );

MultiFieldQueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser( new String[] {"field"}, perFieldAnalyzer );

parser.setDefaultOperator( Operator.AND );

org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = parser.parse( queryString );

FullTextQuery textQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery( luceneQuery, getGenericsClass() );

List searchResult = textQuery.list();
...
```

thanks in advance!

Robert

Comment: Would setting the default operator to OR (`parser.setDefaultOperator( Operator.OR );`) be acceptable?  If so, that's probably the best solution, since it retains the query term, in the case there is, in fact, a match for it ("iffy" or "ifttt" or something like that)

Comment: Unfortunately setting the operator to OR is not convenient. The data basis contains many duplicates. I try to explain: "The capital of.." and ".. Berlin". But only the combination of "capital" and "Belin" in one phrase is suitable.

It look like I have to implement  a second version of the filter chain to get rid of these stopwords.